# Find indented lines under an unindented header

Tags: bash

I need parsing file but I don't know the code for parsing.

The example of file:

```
proces.review_SCAN2.status
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12  
proces.review_SCAN3.status
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12   
proces.kick
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11             
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12       
              OFFLINE OFFLINE                      
proces.test01_ica01.test.opp
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11
```

The result I need:

`grep proces.kick`

```
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11             
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12       
              OFFLINE OFFLINE
```

or

`grep proces.review_SCAN2.status`

```
            ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12
```

I need to find from the name "proces.review_SCAN2.status" until the last line number. I try for regular expression but I do not get it. Can you help me?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to start with what you want to accomplish, and not what you assume the right tools for it are. In this case, `grep` isn't the best choice for the job at all (the problem is better suited to `awk`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` doesn't have a way to store state across lines, making it a poor choice for this job. Consider `awk` instead:

```
findSection() {
  awk -v tgt_section="$1" '
    /^[[:alpha:]]/ { curr_section=$1 }
    /^[[:space:]]/ && curr_section == tgt_section { print $0 }
  '
}

findSection proces.kick <inFile
```

`^[[:alpha:]]` is a regex matching lines which start with an alphabetic character; when the script sees one, it sets the variable `curr_section` to have that value.

`^[[:space:]]` is a regex matching lines which start with whitespace; when the script sees one, it prints it if-and-only-if the `curr_section` and `tgt_section` variables have the same value.

Comment: The result of this is:


              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12
              OFFLINE OFFLINE
              ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11

I need print only 3 lines:

ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca11
ONLINE  ONLINE       tsdumca12 
OFFLINE OFFLINE

Comment: The result is perfectly correct, printing only the three lines you intend, if this exact (copied-and-pasted) code given input copied-and-pasted from your question; see it running in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/c4IpU1. If your input file is different than what you gave us, we can't help you (but you can help *yourself* by forking the ideone instance and figuring out what needs to change to reproduce the bug there).

Comment: Okay... I tried without the function and don't works but if I use de function works well! Thanks for your support!!

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for your support aigan!! Works well!!